# Spring Boot 3.2.0 'oauth2ResourceServer()', 'jwt()','cors()' and 'crsf()' is deprecated and marked for removal

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, okta

Hello I have problem with my Spring boot app, IDE indicaates that my 'oauth2ResourceServer()', 'jwt()','cors()' and 'crsf()' methods are deprecated although (what I have found on the Internet) it's good approach.
When I run the app it crashes. I don't know what to do, I've read manya articles but none of them solved the issue.

```java
package com.mtcompany.ecommerceshop.config;

import com.okta.spring.boot.oauth.Okta;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
import org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationStrategy;
import org.springframework.web.accept.HeaderContentNegotiationStrategy;

@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration {

    @Bean
    protected SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        
        http.authorizeHttpRequests(requests ->
                        requests
                                .requestMatchers("/api/orders/**")
                                .authenticated()
                                .anyRequest().permitAll())
                .oauth2ResourceServer()
                .jwt();

        
        http.cors();
        
        http.setSharedObject(ContentNegotiationStrategy.class, new
                HeaderContentNegotiationStrategy());


        Okta.configureResourceServer401ResponseBody(http);

        http.csrf().disable();

        return http.build();
    }

}
```

[image]

```java
'oauth2ResourceServer()' is deprecated and marked for removal 
'jwt()' is deprecated and marked for removal 
'cors()' is deprecated and marked for removal
'csrf()' is deprecated and marked for removal
```

My pom.xml file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.mtcompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>ecommerce-shop</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>ecommerce-shop</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>21</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.okta.spring</groupId>
            <artifactId>okta-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Migration Guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/5.8/migration/servlet/config.html) configuration part and also current version of `spring-security` [6.2](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/index.html) you have to replace current implementation to next one:

```
  @Bean
  protected SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    
    http.authorizeHttpRequests(requests ->
            requests
                .requestMatchers("/api/orders/**")
                .authenticated()
                .anyRequest().permitAll())
        .oauth2ResourceServer(oAuth -> oAuth.jwt(Customizer.withDefaults()))
        
    http.cors(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable);

    http.setSharedObject(ContentNegotiationStrategy.class, new
        HeaderContentNegotiationStrategy());

    http.csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable);

    return http.build();
  }
```

And also about crashing I guess problem is here:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.okta.spring</groupId>
        <artifactId>okta-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

just try to remove this one dependency and related code and then retry.

Comment: If you upgrade to the `okta-spring-boot-starter` v3.0.6, it should work fine with Spring Boot 3.2.0.